# Is it possible to get the cytoscape.js core object by the selector "#cyContainer"?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm a beginner in cytoscape.js. When a chart is initialized, cytoscape() return a core object "cy", like below:

```
var cy = cytoscape({

  container: document.getElementById('cyContainer'),

  elements: [

  // . . .
})
```

I wonder if it is possible to get the core object by selector "#cyContainer"?

e.g.

```
var cy = $('#cyContainer').cytoscape(); // ??
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no jQuery extension.  Use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) if you want to do instance lookup like that: `map.set( 'cyContainer', cy );`